# Python Itertools permutations with strings

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

i want to use itertools permutations for strings instead of just letters.

```
import itertools
lst = list(permutations(("red","blue"),3))
#This returns []
```

I know i can do something like:

```
a = list(permutations(range(3),3))
for i in range(len(a)):
a[i] = list(map(lambda x: 'red' if x==0 else 'blue' if x==1 else 'green',a[i]))
```

EDIT:
I want to key in this as my input, and get this as my output

```
input: ("red","red","blue")

output:
[(’red’, ’red’, ’red’), (’red’, ’red’, ’blue’),\
(’red’, ’blue’, ’red’), (’red’, ’blue’, ’blue’), (’blue’, ’red’, ’red’), \
(’blue’, ’red’, ’blue’), (’blue’, ’blue’, ’red’), (’blue’, ’blue’, ’blue’)]
```

Comment: what is your expected output? your original idea looks ok to me, the reason why it's returning `[]` is because you're asking for length-3 permutations in a list of length-2 -- there aren't any!

Comment: It works perfectly fine to permute strings. However, you cannot take three elements from a list of two, in any order. That is why you get the empty list as output.

Comment: looks like you want [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `itertools.product` like this:

```
import itertools
lst = list(set(itertools.product(("red","red","blue"),repeat=3))) # use set to drop duplicates
lst
```

`lst` will be:

```
[('red', 'blue', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'red', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'blue', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'blue', 'blue'),
 ('blue', 'red', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'blue', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'red', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'red', 'red')]
```

**Update:**

```
import itertools
lst = list(itertools.product(("red","blue"),repeat=3))
lst
```

output:

```
[('red', 'red', 'red'),
 ('red', 'red', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'blue', 'red'),
 ('red', 'blue', 'blue'),
 ('blue', 'red', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'red', 'blue'),
 ('blue', 'blue', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'blue', 'blue')]
```

Comment: How do i get the same output if my input is just ['red' , 'blue'] and i want the same product?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, also, with `combinations` from `itertools` module, like this example:

```
from itertools import combinations 
final = list(set(combinations(("red","red","blue")*3, 3)))

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[('red', 'blue', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'red', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'blue', 'red'),
 ('blue', 'blue', 'blue'),
 ('blue', 'red', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'blue', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'red', 'blue'),
 ('red', 'red', 'red')]
```